# How long is a piece of $string… too long… javascript P2

Tags: php, javascript

How can I convert this PHP code to JavaScript?

```
$string = "string How Long is a Piece of String?";

if (strlen($string) < 5)
{
   echo "string is less than 5";
}
else
{
   echo "string is more than 5";
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this question just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Did you mean how to implement it in javascript..? If so then you need to at least learn the basics of the language first, if you can't figure out something as trivial as this in it.

Comment: This question deserves an award of some type.

Comment: Did my best, he gave PHP code then asked how to do the same thing in PHP... But it was tagged Javascript. Well, I tried anyway.

Comment: @Carson: I like your question much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is just a really convoluted, badly explained, typo-ridden way of asking how to get the length of a string in JavaScript. If that's the case, just check the length property of the string, like this:

```
var str = 'How long is a piece of string?';
if (str.length < 5) {
  alert('String is less than 5');
} else {
  alert('String is greater than or equal to 5');
}
```

If this is not what you're asking, you really need to clarify the question.